# Vba keep reopening file that have autosave x min and auto close x min

Tags: vba, excel

What needs to be done:

If you open multiple files where this macro is registered, when you make changes, the file will be automatically saved every 5 minutes.

If there are no changes in the file, then it closes the file in a few minutes, while retaining any changes.

I want to reduce the amount of auto-saves by the variable holding "If the file has changed."

I plan to use these macros simultaneously in several open files.

It is very important that the *[If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then ...]* function works so that it is saved only if there are changes.

A link of where this idea was taken:
[http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx]

**Example file
[http://www.planetaexcel.ru/bitrix/components/bitrix/forum.interface/show_file.php?fid=248706&action=download]**

Please let me know of what I'm doing wrong.
thanks

```
Option Explicit 
Public RunWhen As Double 
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 8 ' sec
Public Const cRunWhat = "TheSub" ' the name of the procedure to run
Public RunWhenq As Double 
Public Const cRunIntervalSecondsq = 20 ' sec
Public Const cRunWhatq = "TheSubq" ' the name of the procedure to run
Sub StartTimer() 
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds) 
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _ 
    Schedule:=True 
End Sub 
Sub TheSub() 


    If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then 
        ThisWorkbook.Save 
        StartTimer 

    Else 
        StartTimer 
    End If 


End Sub 


Sub StopTimer() 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _ 
    Schedule:=False 
End Sub 
Sub StartTimerq() 
    RunWhenq = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSecondsq) 
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhenq, Procedure:=cRunWhatq, _ 
    Schedule:=True 
End Sub 
Sub TheSubq() 
    With ActiveWorkbook 
        .Save 
        .Close 
    End With 
End Sub 
Sub StopTimerq() 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhenq, Procedure:=cRunWhatq, _ 
    Schedule:=False 
End Sub 
















Option Explicit 
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Application.Calculation = xlManual 
    StartTimer 
    StartTimerq 
End Sub 
 'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range) 
    Application.Calculation = xlManual 
    ActiveSheet.Calculate 
    StartTimerq 
End Sub 
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _ 
    ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
    StartTimerq 
End Sub 
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object) 
    StartTimerq 
End Sub 
Private Sub Workbook_Activate() 
    StartTimerq 
End Sub 
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
    StopTimerq 
    StopTimer 
End Sub 
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object) 
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "prevsh__", Sh.Name 
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of error are you receiving? It's not said in your question what issue you encountered making it it pretty unclear even after opening your exemple file. Thank you

Comment: You'll need to present an actual *problem* and/or *question*, other than 'let me know what I'm doing wrong." It's not clear to us whether this is already working for you, what issues you may have faced, etc. Does the file just not save? Please be specific about what you're asking so the community can attempt to give you a very direct and accurate answer.